# Get Cookies of HTTP Request of ODATA Service

Tags: javascript, http, cookies, odata, sap-fiori

im facing the problem to send a put http request to an odata service. It works in Postmen with following steps:

1. Send a Get-Request with header: x-csrf-token : fetch and safe the token
2. Send a Put-Request with header: x-csrf-token : token of Get-Request

I noticed, that postmen got the same SessionID Cookie in the Get and the Put Request.

Now I want to build a fiori App, where I want to call the Odata Service.

1. I send a HTTP Get-Request with the fetchAPI whit header x-csrf-token : fetch and safe the token
2. Send a Put-Request with header: x-csrf-token : token of Get-Request.

Now I get a 403 Forbidden Error.

I checked the network tab in the dev tools of chrome and i compared the cookies of both requests. Theire sessionIDs was not equal so i thought I just need to read the cookies of the Get Request and set a Cookie Header in the Put Request to guarantee that both Requests got the same SessionID.

However this does not seem to be possible. If I read the response Header of my Get Request, i does not get the set-cookie header, although it is shown in the network tab. If i call document.cookies i just get an empty string.

So my first Problem is, that I cant read the cookies of my get request. Due to my internet research, it seems like it doesnt work becauce of cross-side problems. But im not sure about this and I do not know how I can solve this error.

In addition to that, im not able to change the cookie header in my Put request. If I set a header:

Cookie: SAPSESSIONID_ : SessionID (e.g my Postman SessionID), this headerline is not shown in my Network Tab and the Session ID of my Put Request is not the ID i wanted to be setted.

I set some headers for the response, like i read in other questions:

'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' - 'Accept,Accept-Language,X-PINGOTHER,Content-Language,Content-Type,Authorization,Cookie,X-Requested-With,Origin,Host'

'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' - 'true'

'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' - 'GET, PUT'

'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' - ''

In my request i already set credentials: 'include' so i think it should work. But I'm still not able to read or set any Cookies...

Code:
GET Request:

```
        const xcsrftokenHeader = new Headers();
        
        xcsrftokenHeader.append('x-csrf-token', 'fetch');
        xcsrftokenHeader.append('Authorization', 'Basic '+  btoa(username + ":" + password));

        const xcsrftokenRequest = new Request('<myURL>', {
            method: 'GET',
            credentials: 'include',
            //crossDomain: true

            
        });
        
        fetch(xcsrftokenRequest)
            .then(response => {
                
                for (var pair of response.headers.entries()){ 
                    console.log(pair[0] + " : " + pair[1]);
                    //I would like to see the set-cookie Cookie here     
                    if(pair[0] == "x-csrf-token"){
                        xcsrftoken =pair[1];
                    }
                }
                

            })
            .catch(error => {console.error('Error', error);});
```

GET (Server)

```
method RFCCHANGEAFOSET_GET_ENTITYSET.
DATA: ls_header1 TYPE ihttpnvp.
  ls_header1-NAME = 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'.
  ls_header1-VALUE = 'Accept,Accept-Language,X-PINGOTHER,Content-Language,Content-Type,Authorization,Cookie,X-Requested-With,Origin,Host'.
  set_header( is_header = ls_header1 ).

  DATA: ls_header2 TYPE ihttpnvp.
  ls_header2-NAME = 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'.
  ls_header2-VALUE = 'true'.
  set_header( is_header = ls_header2 ).

  DATA: ls_header3 TYPE ihttpnvp.
  ls_header3-NAME = 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'.
  ls_header3-VALUE = 'GET, PUT'.
  set_header( is_header = ls_header3 ).

  DATA: ls_header4 TYPE ihttpnvp.
  ls_header4-NAME = 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'.
  ls_header4-VALUE = '<ServerDomain>'.
  set_header( is_header = ls_header4 ).
```

Comment: you can't read cross origin cookies (I assume there's some cross origin request, since you add all these CORS headers on your server ... you are setting those on your server, right?) it's REALLY hard to know what you're doing wrong, since you haven't posted the actual code that has the issue

Comment: yes you're right and i set them on my server. 
I've read in other questions that it should be possible somehow...

Comment: `access-control-allow-origin` needs to be the origin of the request if the request is `withCredentials` ... your question says you set allow origin to `''` ... which is never correct ... do you have any errors in your browser console (I'm assuming there's some web page involved - hard to tell with absolutely no code in the question)

Comment: Sorry I added the Code of the Get Request

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin'.` ... `<ServerDomain>` ... no ... it's the "origin" of the request, not the domain of the server that is sent in that response header ... perhaps you need to [understand CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: Okay thank you, I changed the Entry to the Origin but it doesn't solved the problem.

Comment: 1) you can turn off the cors preflight check in your browser (client side) and check if it is really a cors problem https://alfilatov.com/posts/run-chrome-without-cors/ 
2) the error in the browser -> something like "preflight check not ok" should disappear 
3) since you build a fiori app, you might overwrite your own cookies with the ui5 cookies 
4)  also, SAP (and other) odata services are made for ui interaction and very chatty (text), you might think of using a more sensible way than querying an odata service if you are writing an api. that is a strange usecase you have here  at best

Comment: The `x-csrf-token` value should be the one requested at Fiori LaunchPad startup, you should not request a new one.